# Issue getting ASP.Net and Windows Authentication working on IIS

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, windows-authentication

I have a simple ASP.Net page with VB code running on WIN7 Enterprise VM with IIS 7.5 on which I need to get the visitors domain username on load and store it in a string variable. 
The page is hosted internally on our domain and IIS is setup to authenticate anonymously.

I am getting the username with the following code: **Environment.Username** but of course it always says that the logged on user is IUSR

I installed the Windows Authentication component for IIS but don't know how to get it to work properly. I only started with ASP and IIS last month so I am very new to this. I only want this to apply to a specific folder so I selected it and enabled Windows Authentication, set it NTLM, and disabled Anonymous + ASP Impersenation. That didnt work. I think I tried every combination possible and all I am getting is either error 500, 404 because it tries to redirect to some login page which doesnt exist and sometimes I would get a username/password prompt but even then it wont accept anything

I dont want to prompt users, I just want to pass their existing logon info and open the page. Can someone please tell me how to set this up. I spent all day looking at hundreds of forums and sites and could not get it to work.

I also added the following to the web.config file:

```
<Identify impersonate="true" />
```

Thanks

Comment: what do you have for Authentication mode=? in web.config?

Comment: I don't have anything related to authentication in web.config other than identify impersonate equaled to true. Should I have something else in there? Also, what are the proper settings for authentication in IIS?

Comment: It should be mode="Windows" for your scenario, that is the default if not supplied. You need to make sure Anonymous is disabled and forms is disabled; if forms is enabled, it will probably redirect you to a non-existent login.aspx page.

Comment: you'll need to specify authorized domain users in an authorization in web.config also, otherwise you'll get a windows login prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try adding <authentication mode="Windows" /> in web.config. I already had forms authentication disabled. What do I need to add to web.config to give access to all Authenticated Users or Domain Users? Is it something like <authorization>
      <allow roles="domainname\Authenticated Users" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization> ?

Comment: Thanks @SqlACID I will try your suggestions tomorrow and advise of the results

Comment: When you disable anonymous and enable Windows, what is the error? Without troubleshooting that you won't get anything right, http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs. Impersonation is less relevant at this stage. The 500 and 404 can be caused by completely another thing, so focus on what you should do and don't go the wrong route by "trying every combination"

Comment: @LexLi the resulting error is 404 and its trying to go to the following URL: myvirtualmachine/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=mytestpage.aspx Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Account\Login Logon Method Anonymous Logon User Anonymous

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify authorized users in web.config:

```
 <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="mydomain\someADgroup"/>
      <allow users="mydomain\somuser"/>
      <allow users="*" /> <!-- if you want it open to anybody, as long as they are authenticated-- on the domain!>

    </authorization>
```

Comment: The very first thing I did was try the page with the settings as they were which are:
Anonymous  Disabled, ASP.NET Impersonation Disabled, Forms Authentication Disabled, Windows Authentication: Enabled and set to NTLM.
Web.Config only has:  <identity impersonate="true"/>
Page loaded fine and everything worked. 
I refreshed a few times and everything was fine, then suddenly on refresh it went to HTTP Error 404
Requested URL http://myvirtualmachine/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=mytestpage.aspx
Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Account\Login
Logon Method Anonymous
Logon User Anonymous

Comment: I also tried adding Windows auth and authorization to web config but then getting server 500 error:Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file. Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
The error page highlights the authentication mode=”Windows” line.

Comment: Finally got it working with the help from this article: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/216/Windows-Authentication-With-ASP.NET-Web-Pages - main things I was missing was <add key="EnableSimpleMembership" value="false" />

Comment: Updated link to article which helped with this http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/216/windows-authentication-with-asp-net-web-pages